# Appassembler building wrong class path in generated scripts

Tags: java, maven, appassembler

We use the appassembler plugin in our application.  We are transitioning our maven configuration to create artifacts using classifiers that show what jdk was used to compile it.  Prior to adding profiles and building classified jars, the appassembler happily made a script and built the proper class path to support the script.

However now that the artifact is being built with the classifier it is adding the wrong jar to its classpath.  That is, it is referencing the right groupId, artifactId, and version, but without the classifier.  How do I get appassembler to build the path correctly?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>assemble</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <programs>
            <program>
                <mainClass>com.package.ObjectClass</mainClass>
                <name>ObjectClass</name>
            </program>
        </programs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.jar.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>${jdk.version.display}</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Here is a generic example that shows the problem:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>test.example.TestExample</mainClass>
                        <name>TestExample</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>myClassifier</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you create an example project which shows the possible wrong behaviour and create a jira ticket for it: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MAPPASM. Apart from that could show the full pom file?

Comment: I created and posted a maven pom that shows the problem.  I dont have a login to make a jira at that site.

Comment: @khmarbaise I'd be happy to submit the jira if I had access....